# msbuild addin for VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, visual-studio-addins

I used to use an msbuild addin for VS2008, called "MsBuildAddin" (which was itself based on the now very old Java "NantRunner"). The project page [is here](http://www.netlogics.ch/devcenter/addins.msbuild.html) and the source [is here](http://msbuildaddin.codeplex.com/). It hasn't been updated in a long time, and doesn't work with VS2010 unless you hack the source (which isn't documented at all).

Is there something similar for VS2010? I'm not looking for something different, or more feature-rich, but rather a simple drop-in *replacement* (if such a thing exists).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

http://www.attrice.info/msbuild/

This is the only one I know of

Comment: Preferably looking for something simpler and open source. Thanks though.